# A question about outer measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, self-learning, lebesgue-measure

When two sets are positively separated we know that $\mu(A \cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$. My question is what happens when their intersection is null. Will the above equation be invalid?

My Try:It has to be that the sets A or B should be non measurable or else if both are measurable then i can show that the above equation is valid. But when considering outer measures for non measurable sets i am having a lot of problems. I do not know how to assign an outer measure to non measurable sets. So if anyone can help it would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use Lebesgue measure in the real line.  There is a (non-measurable) subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ such that both $A$ and its complement $B=[0,1]\setminus A$ have outer measure 1.  Then, of course $A \cap B = \varnothing$, but $\mu(A)+\mu(B) = 2 \ne 1 = \mu([0,1]) = \mu(A \cup B)$.

Comment: can you please tell how we get a non measurable set of any size

Comment: Try a Bernstein set: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169714/whats-application-of-bernstein-set