# Can we prove that every non empty perfect set has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ using Bernstein set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, lebesgue-measure, descriptive-set-theory

A set $B\subset \Bbb{R}$ is a Bernstein set if it intersect every perfect subsets of $\Bbb{R}$.

Why Bernstein sets are useful?

1. Any set with positive outer measure contains a non measurable subset.
2. Any set of second category contains a set that lacks the property of Baire.
3. We use Bernstein set to prove the existence of non measurable set with the property of Baire and a measurable set without baire property ( given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4463360/977780)).
4. Bernstein sets are "big " in sense of cardinality (uncountable), in sense of measure (positive outer measure) and in sense of Baire category (second category) but the difference set $d(B)=B-B$ contains no interval.

We can prove that every closed set is the union of a countable set and a perfect set using the point of condensation. Hence every closed uncountable set intersect a perfect set.

**Can we prove that every closed uncountable set intersect a perfect set using Bernstein set ?**

**Can we prove  that every non empty perfect set has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ using Bernstein set ?**

What are other interesting applications of Bernstein set?

Comment: See my [5 February 2006 sci.math post "Remarks on Bernstein sets"](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/sxp7dgz9zTYJ) (an oversight in a couple of statements are corrected in [this follow-up post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/QaaZ0eMcoGQJ)).