# $m^*\left(\displaystyle\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty}[m^*(E_k)]$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is that true that if $\{E_k\}_1^\infty$ is a decreasing countable colection of sets and $m^*(E_1)<\infty$, then
$$m^*\left(\displaystyle\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty}[m^*(E_k)]?$$

I think it's not true, because we don't have that each $E_k$ is measurable.

Does someone know some prove or some counterexample?

PS: m*(A) is the Lebesgue outer measure of A.

Comment: If $E_k$ are not assumed to be measurable sets then the equality does not hold.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764727/general-property-regarding-outer-measure-for-a-nested-sequence-of-sets-measurab

Comment: If $m^*$ is an arbitrary outer measure, the there are trivial counter-examples:

Comment: Let $(\Bbb N, \Sigma, m)$ be a measure space where $\Sigma =\{\emptyset, \Bbb N\}$ and $m$ is a measure defined as $m(\emptyset)=0$ and $m(\Bbb N)=1$. 
It is easy to see that, $m^*(\emptyset)=0$ and, for all $E \subseteq \Bbb N$, if $E\neq \emptyset$, then $m^*(E)=1$. 
For each $k \in \Bbb N$, let $A_k=\{k, k+1, k+2, \cdots \} \subseteq \Bbb N$. 
We have $\bigcap_k A_k = \emptyset$. 
and, for each $k \in \Bbb N$, $A_k \neq \emptyset$. So, $m^*(A_k)=1$. So, we have
$$m^*\left (\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \right) =0 \ne 1= \lim_{k \to \infty} m^{*}(A_k)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the measurable thing is really the point of the question, you're getting into some weird AOC stuff otherwise. I think (assuming the sets are measurable) that the statement is true.

It might be helpful to consider the (increasing) sequence of sets $A_{1} = E_{1}, A_{k} = E_{1}\setminus E_{k}$ for $k=2,3,...$

Their union is $E_{1} \setminus\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}E_{k}$

Try to continue from here :)

Comment: That the statement is true if the sets are measurable is elementary. The whole point of the question is to check the case where the sets are not measurable.

Comment: @Jason Do you have some trivial counterexample that shows that my statement is false?

Comment: @Manatee It's by no means trivial, but check the top answer to the the question Good Morning Captain linked.

Comment: @Jason That's hard to adapt it to my context. I’ve never seen these sets before.

Comment: @Manatee Any counterexamples have to be non-measurable, and non-measurable sets are inherently difficult to describe.