# Example of an uncountable subset of $[0,1]$ with no uncountable closed subsets

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

Question: Find an uncountable set $A \subseteq [0,1]$ s.t. for every uncountable subset $B$ of $A$, $B$ is not closed.

Solution: My guess would be that $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ would be such a set, but I cant seem to prove it. Any help would be great.

Comment: $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$ does not satisfy the condition. Consider the set of numbers whose decimal expansion is of the form:$$0.a_10a_200a_3000a_40000\dotsb$$where $a_i\in\{1,2\}$ for all $i$. That's a closed uncountable subset of $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Comment: The set cannot be Borel, as these contain Cantor sets.

Comment: And in addition to what @Henno said, this implies that the axiom of choice has to be involved.

Comment: Some Bernstein like construction would do it, most likely.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Bernstein+set%22

Comment: The construction given in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/169718/12042) works just as well in $[0,1]$ as it does in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 5):

Recall that a set of reals is called "perfect" if it is closed, nonempty, and without isolated points.  Three standard facts about perfect sets (not requiring the Axiom of Choice) are: (a) every uncountable closed set of reals is the union of a perfect set and a countable set ("Cantor-Bendixson"), (b) every perfect set of reals has the cardinality of the continuum, and (c) there are continuum-many perfect sets.

Using the Axiom of Choice, let $(P_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ be an enumeration of perfect sets (where $\mathfrak{c}$ is the cardinal of the continuum, as per (c) above).  Define two sequences $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ and $(y_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ of real numbers by induction (and again using Choice): assuming the $x_\beta$ and $y_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$ have already been defined, let $x_\alpha$ and $y_\alpha$ be elements of $P_\alpha$ distinct from each other and distinct from all all $x_\beta$ and $y_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$ (this is possible because $P_\alpha$ has cardinality greater than the set of $x_\beta$ and $y_\beta$, per (b) above).  Let $X$ be the set of the $x_\alpha$.  So $X$ has the cardinality of the continuum.  But if $X$ contained an uncountable closed set, then per (a) above it would contain a perfect set $P$, say $P = P_\alpha$, so it would contain $y_\alpha$, a contradiction since the $x_\alpha$ and $y_\alpha$ are disjoint.

Assuming the consistency of an inaccessible cardinal, the Axiom of Choice cannot be dispensed with: it is consistent (relative to the existence of an inaccessible cardinal) that the Axiom of Dependent Choices holds and that every uncountable set of reals has a perfect subset.  The latter statement is, also, a consequence of the Axiom of Determinacy, which is also known to be consistent with Dependent Choices, subject to the consistency of hugely larger cardinals.

Comment: A problem in the American Mathematical Monthly was, verbatim : "A student asserted that every uncountable set of reals contains an uncountable closed subset. Is this (assertion) true?"..... +1.