# Prove that $\mathbb{R}=\sqcup_{i\in \mathfrak{c}}A_i, \mu^*(A_i)>0$

Tags: measure-theory, set-partition, outer-measure

Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ can be partitioned into continuum disjoint sets with positive outer measure.

Comment: Are you sure this is true?

Comment: Perhaps $$ 
\mathbb R = \sqcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}[n-1,n)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition $\mathbb R$ into continuum many disjoint sets (so-called *Bernstein sets*), each of which has nonempty intersection with every uncountable closed set. (A set which meets every uncountable closed set while containing no uncountable closed set is called a [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set).) This is easily done by transfinite induction, since there are just continuum many uncountable closed sets, and every uncountable closed set contains continuum many points.

Comment: neat +1.  do they all have infinite outer measure?

Comment: They all have full outer measure. The complement of each has inner measure zero, as it contains no uncountable closed set.

Comment: related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/169714