# Examples of countable and uncountable Bernstein sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, set-theory

I'm looking for concrete examples of a countable Bernstein set and an uncountable Bernstein set. I haven't been able to find or construct any specific examples so far.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that Bernstein sets are not Lebesgue-measureable

Comment: Do you know the usual construction by transfinite induction? It's not exactly explicit, but it is the best you can get by Brian's answer

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169714/whats-application-of-bernstein-set/169718#169718) I went through the construction mentioned by Alessandro Codenotti.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bernstein sets are non-measurable, so there are no concrete examples: assuming the existence of an inaccessible cardinal, it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that all subsets of the reals are measurable.

All Borel sets are measurable, so there cannot be a countable Bernstein set.