# Carathéodory condition - set example

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

**Definition.** Let $\lambda^*$ denote the Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathbb {R}$. A set $E \in P(\mathbb{R})$  satisfies the [*Carathéodory condition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion) if:
$$ \forall T \in P(\mathbb{R}), \space\space\lambda^*(T) = \lambda^*(T \cap E) + \lambda^*(T \cap E^c)$$

I can not find a set $E$ such that:
$$ \textrm{ for some } T \in P(\mathbb{R}), \space\space\lambda^*(T) <  \lambda^*(T \cap E) + \lambda^*(T \cap E^c)$$

May you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such set by sub-addtivity of outer measures.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Isn't it $ > $ that is forbidden by sub-additivity?

Comment: @GEdgar You are right but OP reversed the inequality after I posted my comment.

Comment: OK, the original question asked about $ > $, and you are right to say it is not possible.  Then the question was changed, but not by the OP.

Comment: thank you all!! This comunity is awesome

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be a [Bernstein set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/169718/442) in $T = [0,1]$.  Then
$\lambda^*(T) = 1$, $\lambda^*(T\cap E) = 1$, $\lambda^*(T\cap E^c) = 1$.

---

Any non-measurable set $E$ will do.  In fact, Lebesgue's definition of "measurable" for unbounded sets $E$ was
$$
\lambda^*(T) = \lambda^*(T \cap E) + \lambda^*(T \cap E^c)
$$
for all intervals $T = [a,b]$.  Carathéodory, when he wanted to generalize to other situations, noted that equivalently you get the same thing if you say "all sets $T$".