# On the Vitali set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It is well known that the Vitali set is unmeasurable. When given a measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{M},\mu)$, can we say that the Vitali set as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is never measurable regardless of the choice of the measure $\mu$?

I know the Vitali set is not Lebesgue measurable, but is the Vitali set unmeasurable in every measure space?

Comment: Certainly not: the function that assigns value $0$ to every subset of $\Bbb R$ is a perfectly good measure, for example, and in this measure every set is measurable. In general, measurability is much more about the measure, not the specific set.

Comment: @Greg: Or the one that assigns $0$ or $1$ based on whether or not $\pi$ is an element of the set.

Comment: Counting measure is another example for which every set is measurable.

Comment: For the record, there is no such thing as **the** Vitali set. We usually refer to **a** Vitali set when we want to indicate a set $S\subseteq \Bbb R$ such that 1) for all $\alpha\in \Bbb R$ there is some $q\in\Bbb Q$ such that $\alpha-q\in S$ and 2) for all $x,y\in S$, either $x=y$ or $x-y\notin \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Another comment.  If you want a set that is non-measurable for many measures, try instead a Bernstein set: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/169714/442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof that a Vitali set is not Lebesgue measurable relies on the fact that Lebesgue measure is invariant under translation.  Unless the measure space $(\mathbb R, \mathcal M, \mu)$ has the property:

> if $A \in \mathcal M$ and $\mu(A) > 0$, then $A+x \in \mathcal M$ and $\mu(A+x) > 0$ for all $x$,

then we cannot expect that argument to work.