# Proof that under the Axiom of Determinacy every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue-measurable.

Tags: set-theory, lebesgue-measure, axiom-of-choice

I was studying Thomas Jech's proof of the above in his book "The Axiom of Choice" (page 178). The proof starts as follows:

"A non-measurable set has different inner and outer measures. In
fact, given a non-measurable set, one can construct a subset of the interval
$[0, 1]$ with inner measure $0$ and outer measure $1$. Thus to show that every
set is measurable, it suffices to show that for every $X\subseteq [0,1]$, either $X$ contains a subset $U$ of positive measure, or $X$ is disjoint from a set $U\subseteq[0,1]$ of positive measure."

My questions are:

- How can one can construct a subset of the interval
  $[0, 1]$ with inner measure $0$ and outer measure $1$ and why does this help us here?
- Why does it suffices to just show this? Why will this imply every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue-measurable?

The definition of Lebesgue-measure Jech's gives is as follows:

The standard way of defining the Lebesgue measure is to define first the outer measure $\lambda^{*}(X)$ of a set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ as the infimum of all possible sums $\sum\left\{ v(I_k) : k \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ where $\left\{ I_k : k \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$ is a collection of $n$-dimensional intervals such that $X \subseteq \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty} I_k$, and $v(I)$ denotes the volume of $I$. For each $X$, $\lambda^{*}(X) \geq 0$ and possibly $= \infty$. A set $X$ is null if $\lambda^{*}(X)=0$.

A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is Lebesgue measurable if for each $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$,
\begin{equation*}
\lambda^{*}(X)=\lambda^{*}(X \cap A) + \lambda^{*}(X \enspace \backslash \enspace A)
\end{equation*}
For a measurable set $A$, we write $\lambda(A)$ instead of $\lambda^{*}(A)$ and call $\lambda(A)$ the Lebesgue measure of $A$.

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly useful is [this 5 February 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/GCl-79BcPXM/m/sxp7dgz9zTYJ). See also the MSE question [How to construct a Bernstein set and what are their applications?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/169714/13130) and [these questions linked to it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/169714?lq=1). Also the mathoverflow questions [Demystifying the Caratheodory Approach to Measurability](https://mathoverflow.net/q/34007/15780) and [Why is Lebesgue measure theory asymmetric?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/308856/15780)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Great! I'll get reading. Thank you, Dave.