# Must every real function be bounded on a non-negligble set?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any real function. Must there be a "non-negligible" set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(S)$ is bounded? "Non-negligible" is open to interpretation. We can take it to mean that the closure of $S$ has nonempty interior. Alternatively, we can take it to mean that $S$ has positive measure. A̶l̶t̶e̶r̶n̶a̶t̶i̶v̶e̶l̶y̶,̶ ̶w̶e̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶s̶i̶m̶p̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶m̶e̶a̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶$̶S̶$̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶u̶n̶c̶o̶u̶n̶t̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ (edit: solution to this below). The answerer may choose any of these interpretations (or an alternative one, if he feels it is relevant).

I'm aware of the existence of some pathological functions like the Conway Base $13$ function. This is a function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with the property that any nonempty open set is mapped to $\mathbb{R}$. However, I'm not sure whether or not this is a counterexample to any of the claims above.

We can indeed find an uncountable $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ with $f(S)$ bounded. Consider that $$\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} f^{-1}([n, n+1])$$ hence there must exist an $n$ such that $f^{-1}([n, n+1])$ is uncountable. Hoping for a stronger result.

Comment: I suggest you make up your mind and ask a concrete question.

Comment: I realized that this question is a partial duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376060/is-there-a-function-unbounded-on-all-sets-with-positive-measure). In that answer, a non-measurable $f$ is constructed which is unbounded on all sets of positive measure.

Comment: It is true, however, that there is an $S$ whose closure has nonempty interior. This follows immediately from [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72800/every-real-function-has-a-dense-set-on-which-its-restriction-is-continuous) result, which I was actually aware of beforehand, but didn't realize the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar argument to the one you provide shows that if $f$ is measurable, then there must be a positive-measure set on which $f$ is bounded: since $\infty=m(\mathbb R)=\sum m(f^{-1}([n,n+1]))$, $f^{-1}([n,n+1])$ must have positive measure for some $n$.