# Does there exist a Lebesgue nonmeasurable set whose measurable subsets are all null sets?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure.

Let $A$ be a Lebesgue-nonmeasurable set.

Define $S:=\{E\subset A : E\text{ is Lebesgue measurable}\}$.

Does there exists a nonmeasurable set $A$ satisfying $\forall E\in S, \mu(E)=0$?

Comment: let $B$ be a measurable set of measure 3, say disjoint from $A$. Then $A\cup B$ is not measurable but has a measurable subset of positive measure

Comment: @user126154 Edited:)

Comment: It seems to me that the argument used by user126154 is still applicable, am I wrong?

Comment: @alex How so? $A\cup B$ has a measure 3 subset

Comment: In other words, I'm asking whether there exists a *nonmeasurable boundary* between null sets and positive measures

Comment: This question was according to be satisfactorily answered in another thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/the-subset-of-non-measurable-set . The name Vitali set might not be familiar but the standard construction of a nonmeasurable set using countably many disjoint Cantor sets is probably familiar can be taken a more concrete example (see Stein Real analysis p. 25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An arbitrary non-measurable subset $A$ with  inner Lebesgue measure zero  has the property indicated by John in his question. Such are  for example,  Vitali  and  Bernstein sets.

Comment: Assuming the continuum hypothesis you can do even better (or worse, depending on your point of view), namely, you can construct a nonmeasurable set $A$ such that every measurable subset of $A$ is countable.