# Two questions regarding nonmeasurable sets of real numbers.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $S$ is a set of real of numbers with strictly positive Lebesgue measure. Does there exist a subset $N$ of $S$ such that $N$ is non-Lebesgue measurable? My second question is, suppose $N$ is a non-Lebesgue measurable set of reals. Does there exist an $\epsilon > 0$, such that for all $\delta$ with $0 < \delta \leq \epsilon$, there exists a subset $M$ of $N$ such that $M$ is Lebesgue measurable with the measure of $M$ equal to $\delta$?

Comment: These are good questions, but they have been asked here before: your first question has a positive answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287212/non-measurable-subset-of-a-positive-measure-set?rq=1), and your second question has a negative answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700298/does-there-exist-a-lebesgue-nonmeasurable-set-whose-measurable-subsets-are-all-n?rq=1). (I've used the former as the duplicate target since we can only pick one.)

Comment: Besides the MSE questions/answers @Noah Schweber cited, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4537548/13130) gives links to more precise results and states a conjecture that might be suitable for an undergraduate or Masters project, especially if examples can be proved to not exist for all the possibilities described.