# Does any nonmeasurable set with infinite outer measure contain a closed set with infinite (outer) measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a non-measurable set with infinite Lebesgue outer measure, i.e., $m^*(A)=\infty$. Does there exist a ${\bf closed}$ subset $F\subset A$ with (infinite Lebesgue (outer) measure) $m^*(F)=\infty$?

I think the answer is "positive", but what would be an easy answer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as motivated by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/the-subset-of-non-measurable-set). Take a Vitali set in $[0, 1]$ and any closed subset (which is measurable) has measure $0$. Now take a countable union of disjoint translates of this set for your counterexample.