# If E is measurable, inner and outer measure could differ?

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I got stuck in this question and I can't find a counterexample.  I proved that this is true:

If ${|E|_e}<\infty\Rightarrow$ E is measurable $\Leftrightarrow{|E|_i}={|E|_e}$. Where ${|E|_i}$ and ${|E|_e}$ stand risp. for inner and outer measure.
Well, I cannot find a counterexample in the case when E has infinite outer measure. My book says it is not true but nothing comes to my mind. Everything I think of, has some closed subset with infinite measure so the equivalence still holds. To find one, I should find a set whose closed subsets have all finite measure or such that they are not measurable,right? Any ideas or suggestions?

P.s for those who do not know, the inner measure of E is defined by ${|E|_i}$= sup|F| where F$\subset$E is closed.

Comment: So you state that every finite Borel measure is regular? I don't know. It is suspicious though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does any nonmeasurable set with infinite outer measure contain a closed set with infinite (outer) measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676866/does-any-nonmeasurable-set-with-infinite-outer-measure-contain-a-closed-set-with)

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  Althouth, as your correctly pointed, it is not true that every non-measurable set of infinity outer measure contains a closed set of infinite outer measure, the question here is different. 

As I understand, the OP is not asking about "every", but just asking if there is one counter-exemple to show that, if $E$ has infinite outer measure, then we may have $ |E|_i=|E|_e=+\infty$ and $E$ be non-measurable. Of course, such counter-example exists.

Comment: @Ramiro You're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple counter-exemple: a non-measurable set $E$ such that $|E|_i=|E|_e=+\infty$

Let $A$ be a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$.  Take $E=(-\infty,-1] \cup A$. Clearly $E$ is non-measurable. We also have that
$$ |E|_i \geqslant |(-\infty,-1] |_i =+\infty$$
and
$$ |E|_e \geqslant |(-\infty,-1] |_e =+\infty$$
So, we have $|E|_i=|E|_e=+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! It really helped me :)

Comment: @FilippoLeggio Welcome to Stack Exchange Mathematics. I am glad to have helped you. If If my answer answers completely your question, please, accept it, by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.